# Multinode cluster only recognizes 1 live node

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have the exact same error as in this post.
http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Multinode-cluster-only-recognizes-1-node-td3997585.html

How can i solve this problem?

**Edit:**

We want to run a 2 node cluster. Our code works perfectly. 
We have a master node and a slave node. Since we want to use master node also as a slave we've configured master and slave files as:

```
conf/master:
master

conf/slave:
master
slave
```

When I run bin/start-all.sh on my master node, jps gives these as expected:

```
namenode
secondarynamenode
jobtracker
datanode
tasktracker
jps
```

jps on the slave node gives these as expected:

```
datanode
tasktracker
jps
```

Everything works great. Our configuration mapred-site, core-site knows master ip and ports. Replication factor is set to 2 in hdfs-site.xml.

On this configuration mapreduce application runs. But I guess it only runs on the masternode's jobtracker. when I look at jobtracker user interface, node number is 1.

Another scenario:

If I do not want to use master as a slave also, I change the masters and slaves files like this:

```
conf/masters:
master

conf/slaves:
slave
```

Now jps on the maste rnode gives:

```
namenode
secondarynamenode
jobtracker
jps
```

jps on the slave node gives these as expected:

```
datanode
tasktracker
jps
```

In this configuration it gives me "could only be replicated 0 instead of 1" error. I've added the complete console output at the end.

By the way hadoop_home directory paths are identical for both nodes. It is not a problem anymore.

What could be the problem?

complete console output:

```
[adminuser@localhost hadoop-1.1.2]$ bin/hadoop jar /home/adminuser/Desktop/proje/proje.jar  arkadasoner.Main hdfs://10.0.2.15:9000/input/id.txt hdfs://10.0.2.15:9000/output/x.txt hdfs://10.0.2.15:9000/output/y.txthdfs://10.0.2.15:9000/output/z.txt

13/06/16 14:36:59 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
13/06/16 14:36:59 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /tmp/hadoop-adminuser/mapred/staging/adminuser/.staging/job_201306161433_0001/job.jar could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1639)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:736)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:578)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1393)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1389)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1387)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:62)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.locateFollowingBlock(DFSClient.java:3686)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSClient.java:3546)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.access$2600(DFSClient.java:2749)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSClient.java:2989)

13/06/16 14:36:59 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Error Recovery for block null bad datanode[0] nodes == null
13/06/16 14:36:59 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Could not get block locations. Source file "/tmp/hadoop-adminuser/mapred/staging/adminuser/.staging/job_201306161433_0001/job.jar" - Aborting...
13/06/16 14:36:59 INFO mapred.JobClient: Cleaning up the staging area hdfs://10.0.2.15:9000/tmp/hadoop-adminuser/mapred/staging/adminuser/.staging/job_201306161433_0001
13/06/16 14:36:59 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:adminuser cause:org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /tmp/hadoop-adminuser/mapred/staging/adminuser/.staging/job_201306161433_0001/job.jar could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1639)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:736)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:578)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1393)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1389)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1387)

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /tmp/hadoop-adminuser/mapred/staging/adminuser/.staging/job_201306161433_0001/job.jar could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1639)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:736)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:578)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1393)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1389)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1387)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:62)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.locateFollowingBlock(DFSClient.java:3686)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSClient.java:3546)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.access$2600(DFSClient.java:2749)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSClient.java:2989)
13/06/16 14:36:59 ERROR hdfs.DFSClient: Failed to close file /tmp/hadoop-adminuser/mapred/staging/adminuser/.staging/job_201306161433_0001/job.jar
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /tmp/hadoop-adminuser/mapred/staging/adminuser/.staging/job_201306161433_0001/job.jar could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1639)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:736)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:578)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1393)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1389)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1387)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:62)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.locateFollowingBlock(DFSClient.java:3686)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSClient.java:3546)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.access$2600(DFSClient.java:2749)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSClient.java:2989)
```

Comment: Would you mind typing 'your' problem here?Also, showing the logs would be helpful. I didn't quite get that question. What does JPS show in your master and slaves machines?How many slaves do you have?

Answer (score 1):

You please check that in every master + slave configurations files use a single IPaddress or hosts like hdfs://master:54310 (it should be the same on every master and slave). where master  is the hostname in my /etc/hosts file pointing to the master node.

I also faced the same problem but I was using hdfs://localhost:54310 on all of my nodes, then I changed it to hdfs://master:54310 or hdfs://x.x.x.x:54310 where x.x.x.x is the address of the master node.